# How to create common methods between 2 interfaces

Tags: c#, interface, abstraction

```
class Program
{
    interface I1
    {
        void F1();
    }

    interface I2
    {
        void F2();
    } //2 interfaces

    abstract class b1 : I1
    {
        abstract public void F1();
    }

    private class d1 : b1
    {
        public override void F1()
        {
            Console.Write("Inside D1:b1.F1");

            //I want to call my method() here
            MyMethod();
        }
    }

    private class d2 : b1
    {
        public override void F1()
        {
            Console.Write("Inside d2:b1.F1");

            //I want to call my method() here
            MyMethod();
        }
    }

   private class ImeplementI2_1 : I2
    {
        public void F2()
        {
            //Implementation
            Console.Write("Inside b_1:b_1.F2");

            //I want to call my method() here
            MyMethod();
        }
    }

   private class ImeplementI2_2 : I2
   {
       public void F2()
       {
           //Implementation
           Console.Write("Inside b_1:b_1.F2");

           //I want to call my method() here
           MyMethod();
       }
   }

    void MyMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Printmenow");
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        I1 interface1;

        if (args.Length > 0)
        {
            interface1 = new d1();

        }
        else
        {
            interface1 = new d2();
        }

        interface1.F1();
        //I want to call my method() here
        MyMethod();

    }

}
```

Where would be the best to implement MyMethod() ? I have 2 interfaces have same method implemented differently. So i thought about it and seems i can only go with static method in that Class Program to make everyone happy. Any suggestions or better solutions ?

Comment: "I have 2 interfaces have smae method implemented differently" Why?

Comment: Sounds like you need an abstract class.

Comment: Why exactly do you need this ? Please provide more details regarding your problem because as it is for now it's difficult to say anything

Comment: seems you just need use [explicit implementation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Either use base type:

```
interface IA {}
interface IB {}

class Base
{
    protected void MyMethod() {}
}

class A : Base, IA {}
class B : Base, IB {}
```

or static method (probably, of a static class):

```
static class MyHelper()
{
    public static void MyMethod() {}
}
```

or make some sort of a service, and use this service as a dependency (you may consider using of dependency injection here):

```
interface IMyService
{
    void MyMethod();
}

class MyService : IMyService
{
    public void MyMethod() {}
}

class A : Base, IA 
{
    private readonly IMyService service;

    public A(IMyService service)
    {
        this.service = service;
    }

    // IA implementation
}

class B : Base, IB 
{
    private readonly IMyService service;

    public B(IMyService service)
    {
        this.service = service;
    }

    // IB implementation
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add another interface as base interface for those two

```
interface IMyMethodable
{
    void MyMethod(); 
}

interface I1 : IMyMethodable
{
    void F1();
}

interface I2 : IMyMethodable
{
    void F2();
} //2 interfaces
```

If you want to access MyMethod of Program class you can do two things:

1) just declare it as Static

2) pass it as delegate and call in your classes

Comment: Where would you implement it ? I dont want to implement twice as the functionality of this MyMethod() same consumes some external library calls. ?

Comment: He doesn't need both interfaces to *expose* `MyMethod`, he needs all implementations of either interface to have access to that method.

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand correctly that in method d1.F1 you want to call a method named MyMethod() and in d2.F1 you also want to call the same method named MyMethod().

You don't specify to which class MyMethod() belongs, but apparently it is something that both d1 and d2 can call. Besides they call the same MyMethod. I guess you ought to put MyMethod in the common superclass of both d1 and d2 which in your case would be b1.

Can you say: "Every b1 has the same MyMethod()? Then it definitely belongs in b1

Consider class Shape and subclasses like rectangle, oval and sub-subclasses like square and circle.

If you say the every Shape has one Point that we would call the position of the Shape, then GetPosition would definitely be a function of Shape.

However, although every Shape has an Area, the way you calculate the area of a rectangle is very different than the area of a circle. GetArea() is a typical example of a function that would be places in the interface, or maybe as an abstract function of Shape.

Comment: Thanks, MyMethod() is completely new i have to write which will invoke bunch of other library calls. Infact, i have to implement 3 of MyMethods. So i can create a new class or define inside this too. But want to understand whats the best/optimal solution here

Answer (score -1):

You're quite right that if you have a particular method that you've written that you want to be accessible from any given class and that doesn't need any object instance to store any state then you want a `public static` method.  In your example it would *work* to have it within `Program`, although in any non-toy example I would strongly encourage you to not nest all of this within a `Program` class.  All of these types should be top level types, and `MyMethod` should be a static method of some new type that represents whose responsibility it is to perform such an operation.